# EWS Managed API Timezone "Unable to convert"

Tags: c#, timezone, exchangewebservices, ews-managed-api

I use EWS Managed API 2.1 and initialized my ExchangeService with all system time zones found on my Win 2008 R2 (German) IIS server with up-to-date patchlevel:

```
EWS ews;
string s = "";
foreach (TimeZoneInfo tz in TimeZoneInfo.GetSystemTimeZones()) {
  try {
    ews = new ExchangeService(ExchangeVersion.Exchange2010, tz);
    ews.Credentials = new WebCredentials("alex@contoso.com", "password");
    ews.AutodiscoverUrl("alex@contoso.com");
    Appointment app = new Appointment(ews);
    app.Start = DateTime.Now;
    app.End = DateTime.Now.AddMinutes(15);
    app.Subject = tz.Id;
    app.Save();
  } catch(Exception ex) { s += ex.Message + "\n"; }
}
```

I get errors with some timezones. The error messages are:

```
Unable to convert 2009-01-01T00:00:00.000 from (UTC-03:00) Buenos Aires to UTC.
Unable to convert 2012-01-01T00:00:00.000 from (UTC-03:00) Salvador to UTC.
Unable to convert 2012-01-01T00:00:00.000 from (UTC+02:00) Tripolis to UTC.
Unable to convert 2009-01-01T00:00:00.000 from (UTC+04:00) Port Louis to UTC.
Unable to convert 2009-01-01T00:00:00.000 from (UTC+08:00) Perth to UTC.
```

Could someone explain to me, as simple as possible,

- why these conversions are tried by the dll code?
- why they would fail?
- whether/how I can circumvent this problem?

Comment: How are you getting error messages with years 2009 and 2012 when your code is using `DateTime.Now`?

Comment: @MattJohnson That's exactly what I want to know...

Answer (score 0):

This is just a guess, but it might be due to `DateTime.Now` having "local" kind, while you're using a different time zone.  Consider specifying the time in the target time zone:

```
var now = TimeZoneInfo.ConvertTimeFromUtc(DateTime.UtcNow, tz);
app.Start = now;
app.End = now.AddMinutes(15);
```

You might also want to specify the start and end time zones explicitly.  I'm not sure if it matters or not, but you could test:

```
app.StartTimeZone = tz;
app.EndTimeZone = tz;
```

Sorry I don't have an Exchange server handy to test these assumptions, but you could try and see if it works for you.

Answer (score 0):

This is a bug in .Net https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/1027179/timezone-conversion-bug

I used this workaround

```
        var timeZoneInfo = GetWorkaroundTimeZone(TimeZoneInfo.Local);
        var appointment = new Appointment(service)
                          {
                              Subject = subject,
                              Body = body,
                              Start = start,
                              StartTimeZone =  timeZoneInfo,
                              End = end,
                              EndTimeZone = timeZoneInfo
                          };

    private static TimeZoneInfo GetWorkaroundTimeZone(TimeZoneInfo timeZone)
    {
        try
        {
            TimeZoneInfo.ConvertTime(new DateTime(2014, 1, 1), timeZone, TimeZoneInfo.Utc);
            TimeZoneInfo.ConvertTime(new DateTime(2012, 1, 1), timeZone, TimeZoneInfo.Utc);
            TimeZoneInfo.ConvertTime(new DateTime(2009, 1, 1), timeZone, TimeZoneInfo.Utc);
            return TimeZoneInfo.Local;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            return TimeZoneInfo.CreateCustomTimeZone(
                "Time zone to workaround bug",
                timeZone.BaseUtcOffset,
                "Time zone to workaround bug",
                "Time zone to workaround bug");
        }
    }
```